# installing nginx module from bash script doesn't work

Tags: linux, bash, nginx

I use Nginx v16.1.1 and I want to install modsecurity.

If I run the commands listed below from command line, the ModSecurity module will appear in "nginx -V" as an installed module.

However, if I execute the script as file (e.g. ./myscript.sh) it doesn't install the module as expected.

```
#!/bin/sh

# Download and Install libModSecurity
cd /opt/
git clone https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity
cd ModSecurity
git checkout v3/master
sh build.sh
git submodule init
git submodule update
./configure

# Build libModSecurity
make && make install
make check

# Download the ModSecurity Nginx connector
cd /opt/
git clone https://github.com/SpiderLabs/ModSecurity-nginx.git

#########
# Nginx #
#########

echo "Installing Nginx..."

# Download latest stable version
NGINX_VER='nginx-1.16.1'
cd /opt/
echo "Downloading $NGINX_VER..."
wget http://nginx.org/download/$NGINX_VER.tar.gz
tar xvzf $NGINX_VER.tar.gz
cd $NGINX_VER

./configure --prefix=/usr/share/nginx \
--with-debug \
--add-module=/opt/ModSecurity-nginx \
--with-cc-opt='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic' \
--with-ld-opt=' -Wl,-E'

# Install
make && make install

# Check installed modules
nginx -V
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "run the script as a script" and how does this differ from "run the script manually"?

Comment: @tripleee edited

Comment: If you installed `nginx` before, just `nginx` in a script probably runs the one you originally installed. What does `type nginx` output in these two scenarios?

Answer (score 0):

The `\` after `./configure` will prevent `--with-debug` being read as a command which is probably what is probably what's causing this (if you have the necessary permissions)

```
./configure \
--with-debug \
--add-module=/opt/ModSecurity-nginx \
--with-cc-opt='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic' \
--with-ld-opt=' -Wl,-E'
```